Cannot find module when running test in Jest
Im trying to setup tests for my company's app. The app runns perfectly, but when i run tests i get the following error:
 Cannot find module @myCompany/custom-react-components from 'src/contentArea/detailPages/components/DetailPageSections.tsx'

This is my test
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react"
import App from "./App"

describe("App component", () => {
    test("Renders App component correctly", () => {
        render(<App />)
        const appComponent = screen.getByText(/Click me/i)
        expect(appComponent).toBeInTheDocument()
    })
})

I also tried to configure the moduleMappers in the jest.config file which looks like this currently
 moduleNameMapper: {
        "^@myCompany/custom-react-components/components$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/@myCompany/custom-react-components/dist/components/index.js",
        "^@myCompany/custom-react-components$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/@myCompany/custom-react-components/dist/index.js",
    },

We are using custom react components which are hosted on aws code artifact. Also if I try to test components which do not include custom components the tests run smooth. I have the feeling that he module mappers are not set correctly, but I tried every possible solution, without success.
What I also noticed is that the custom components which are located like this:
@myCompany/custom-components/dist/components
And some are structured like this:
@myCompany/custom-components/dist/components/tileView
The second one seems to be the issue.
